# repository in rest controller catch error "Parameter 1 of constructor could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot-test

I make JUnit tests for SpringBoot rest controllers. When i start tests i get the next error:

[image]

I suppose it appears because of BookRepository class is autowired into Controller class. Because of legacy i cannot change this Controller class.
What i need to do?

In addition this is my test method:

Here are emulation of real code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = AuthorController.class, secure = false)
public class AuthorControllerTest {
    private static final Long AUTHOR_ID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AuthorService authorService;

    AuthorShortDTO authorShortDTO;
    AuthorShortDTO authorShortDTO1;
    List<AuthorShortDTO> authorShortDTOList;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        authorShortDTO = new AuthorShortDTO();
        authorShortDTO.setId(1L);
        authorShortDTO.setFirstName("Alex");
        authorShortDTO.setMiddleName("");
        authorShortDTO.setLastName("Menn");

        authorShortDTO1 = new AuthorShortDTO();
        authorShortDTO1.setId(2L);
        authorShortDTO1.setFirstName("Den");
        authorShortDTO1.setMiddleName("");
        authorShortDTO1.setLastName("Rob");

        authorShortDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

        authorShortDTOList.add(authorShortDTO);
        authorShortDTOList.add(authorShortDTO1);
    }

    @Test
    public void getAuthorsTest() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(authorService.getAuthors()).thenReturn(authorShortDTOList);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
            "/author").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        String expected = "[{id:1, firstName:Alex, middleName:, lastName:Menn}, " +
            "{id:2, firstName:Den, middleName:, lastName:Rob}]";

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, result.getResponse()
            .getContentAsString(), false);
    }
```

Rest controller class:

```
@RestController
public class AuthorController extends BasicExceptionHandler {

    private final AuthorService service;

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;//if i exclude this repo it will ok when testing

    @Autowired
    public AuthorController(AuthorService service, BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.service = service;
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/author", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<AuthorShortDTO> getAuthors() {
        return service.getAuthors();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/author/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AuthorShortDTO getAuthor (
            @PathVariable("id") long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        bookRepository.getOne(1L);//emulate real code

        return service.getAuthor(id);
    }
 ...
}
```

Error message from Intellij output:

```
2018-10-04 20:49:24.258  WARN 6982 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorController' defined in file [/home/max/java_projects/bookshelter/serverparent/rest/target/classes/ru/arvsoft/server/rest/controller/AuthorController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.arvsoft.server.core.repository.BookRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2018-10-04 20:49:24.265  INFO 6982 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-04 20:49:24.316 ERROR 6982 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in ru.arvsoft.server.rest.controller.AuthorController required a bean of type 'ru.arvsoft.server.core.repository.BookRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ru.arvsoft.server.core.repository.BookRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Post the text/code please. Some of us don't have good eyes, and others of us don't headcompile.

Comment: Actually, only exception is needed + related classes.

Comment: That fails in tests right?

Comment: The Head Rush, ok, i deleted one class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> required a bean of type
>   'ru.arvsoft.server.core.repository.BookRepository' that could not be
>   fou

Thats kid of self explainatory isnt it? Your tested beans requires `BookRepository` but you are not creating one in the context (nor mocking it). Add

```
@MockBean
private BookRepository bookRepository;
```

Comment: I do not use BookRepository in my test class, it is used in Controller class.

Comment: And your controller requires book repository isnt it? Thats what constructor says `public AuthorController(AuthorService service, BookRepository bookRepository) {`

Comment: Yes. As you can see my Controller use BookRepository.

Comment: So do what i wrote.

Comment: I added but not result. It looks as unused variable

Comment: I know it's bad practice to inject repository in controller but it is legacy production code

Comment: Cannot be, it works the same as you injected your service.

Comment: In my Controller test class i do not use BookRepository directly.

Comment: @jlemon so what was that *I added but not result. It looks as unused variable* ?

Comment: Yes, as unused, but it works you offered. I suppose that `@WebMvcTest(value = AuthorController.class, secure = false)` rise context just around this class and i need to say Spring to include Repository class